# How to update one attribute in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

How to update only :share_count, maybe this should be done with `upsert` ?
I use ruby on rails and mongoid

```
  class FeedEntry
  include Mongoid::Document
  require 'social_shares'

  field :name, type: String
  field :url, type: String
  field :share_count, type: Integer

  before_save :load_shares

  def load_shares
    self.share_count = SocialShares.total url, %w(sharedcount)
  end

  def self.update_shares_today
    @feed_entries = FeedEntry.today.all
    @feed_entries.each do |feed_entry|
      feed_entry.update
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count = SocialShares.total url, %w(sharedcount)
update_attributes share_count: count
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `upsert`? `upsert` is about updating or creating a record, not about updating single attribute